# React Native error on android "Cannot read property 'setDryRun' of null, js engine:hermes"

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-hermes

I am developing a react native application which is working absolutely fine on iOS but when I ran application on android, I got this error [image: Error Image]
I did a lot of RnD but didn't any solution. I may think it is may be due to any specific library this package.json file

```
"scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "1.19.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "9.4.1",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "18.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "18.3.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "18.3.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "6.6.3",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.7",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.9.13",
    "formik": "2.4.2",
    "mobx": "6.10.0",
    "mobx-react": "9.0.0",
    "moment": "2.29.4",
    "native-base": "^3.4.28",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.72.3",
    "react-native-document-picker": "9.0.1",
    "react-native-flash-message": "0.4.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.12.0",
    "react-native-htmlview": "0.16.0",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "0.40.0",
    "react-native-material-dropdown": "0.11.1",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "17.0.0",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "1.0.2",
    "react-native-paper": "5.9.1",
    "react-native-pdf": "^6.7.1",
    "react-native-render-html": "6.3.4",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "3.23.0",
    "react-native-size-matters": "0.4.0",
    "react-native-svg": "12.1.1",
    "react-native-webview": "13.2.3",
    "react-redux": "8.1.1",
    "redux": "4.2.1",
    "redux-thunk": "2.4.2",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native/eslint-config": "^0.72.2",
    "@react-native/metro-config": "^0.72.9",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.76.7",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=16"
  }
```

this is my build.gradle project file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle')
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15'
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
}
```

and this is my build.gradle app file

```
android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    namespace "com.tavrtalk"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tavrtalk"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst 'lib/x86/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/arm64-v8a/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/x86_64/libc++_shared.so'
        pickFirst 'lib/armeabi-v7a/libc++_shared.so'
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // The version of react-native is set by the React Native Gradle Plugin
    implementation("com.facebook.react:react-android")
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:32.2.0')
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}")
    if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I am new to react native and any kind of help would be appreciated